# Show that a infinite discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to prove that a set which is discrete in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the euclidean topology) and infinite cannot be an algebraic set. How could I do it?

Comment: Just asking: Do you have any ideas in the case $n = 1$?

Comment: yes, that case is not difficult you only have to know that the zariski topology agree with the cofinite topology (and that is proved using that the polynomials (not zero) in one variable has finitely many zeros), but i don't know how to prove that in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

If $V$ is infinite discrete, then the ring $k[V]$ of regular functions on $V$ is the direct product of infinitely many copies of $k$, therefore not noetherian.  But the ring of regular functions on an affine algebraic variety is a quotient $k[X_1,\ldots , X_n]/I(V)$ of a polynomial ring, therefore noetherian.

---

Yet another approach: Show that the ring $k[V]=k[X_1,\ldots , X_n]/I(V)$ has only finitely many maximal ideals.  This most likely requires one or two subtle facts about dimension, but this follows directly from either primary decomposition or noether normalization.

Comment: how do you prove that? the first statement

Comment: @lecheconmilo If your definition of a regular function is a $k$-valued function that is rational in some neighborhood of each point, then this is a direct consequence of the fact that, in a discrete topology, every point is a neighborhood of itself.